# Composer Fails to Install and Update

Tags: php, installation, composer-php

I was doing the same thing in my server weeks ago, but now I can't. Here's my error output:

> composer install

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:974
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'proc_open(): fo...', 'phar:///usr/loc...', 974, Array)
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(974): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, Array)
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(793): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getSttyColumns()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(754): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDimensions()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(688): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWidth()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/com in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 974

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:974
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'proc_open(): fo...', 'phar:///usr/loc...', 974, Array)
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(974): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, Array)
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(793): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getSttyColumns()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(754): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDimensions()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(688): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWidth()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/com in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 974`
```

Answer (score 3):

I once had this problem, increasing memory limit solved it. You can give it a try.

Comment: How would you do this?  In the php.ini file?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, increase the swap memory:

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding composer.lock to tracked files solved the problem.

```
git add -f composer.lock
git add .
git commit -m 'remove composer.lock from ignored files'
git push
```

and then,

```
git clone ....
```

in server.

Problem solved.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: You MUST commit the `composer.lock` file because otherwise a call to `composer install` will actually behave like `composer update`, which is memory consuming and will probably not install the versions you tested with.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running under virtual environment like vagrant for instance, then make sure swap is enabled. Run below script to create swap

```
#!/bin/sh

# size of swapfile in megabytes
swapsize=512

# does the swap file already exist?
grep -q "swapfile" /etc/fstab

# if not then create it
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo 'swapfile not found. Adding swapfile.'
   fallocate -l ${swapsize}M /swapfile
   chmod 600 /swapfile
   mkswap /swapfile
   swapon /swapfile
   echo '/swapfile none swap defaults 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
else
   echo 'swapfile found. No changes made.'
fi

# output results to terminal
cat /proc/swaps
cat /proc/meminfo | grep Swap
```

source: http://www.nyayapati.com/srao/2014/05/youcompleteme-install-fails-due-to-internal-compiler-error/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue below update command fixed my problem.

sudo composer self-update

//this will set memory.
php -dmemory_limit=-1 composer update

or

sudo php -dmemory_limit=-1 composer update

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issues with updating symfony project with large dependencies. Creating swap file helped:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have run 2 command.
**shailesh@ubuntu$ /var/www$ sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024**  
Output will be looking like this:
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 13.1359 s, 81.7 MB/s

and after that run
**shailesh@ubuntu$ sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1**
Output will be like:
 
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 1048572 KiB
no label, UUID=486b676c-aa2a-4329-9783-6d1e6a9eb0a5

and final command you have to run 
**shailesh@ubuntu$ sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1**

Now run composer update and save time.

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me `php -dmemory_limit=1GB $(which composer) update`